# PowerShell Close File/Delete File After Emailing via .NET

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm stuck at the end of a script I am working on where a file is emailed out before being deleted. Except.. the file seems to be still be opened, likely by the SMTP client, so I get an error when I try to delete it. Of course restarting a shell will let me delete it, thats not the point. ;-) Point is I'd like to create it, email it, delete it, in one script.

The Error:

```
   Cannot remove item C:\Temp\myfile.csv: The process cannot access the file
    'C:\Temp\myfile.csv' because it is being used by another process.
```

Code:

```
$emailFrom = 'noreply@localhost'
$emailTo = 'aaron@localhost'
$smtpServer = 'localhost'

$FileName='myfile.csv'
$FilePathName='c:temp\' + $FileName

$subject = 'Emailing: ' + $FileName
$body = 'This message as been sent with the following file or link attachments: ' + $FileName

$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($FilePathName)
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

$msg.From = $emailFrom
$msg.To.Add($emailTo)
$msg.Subject = $subject
$msg.Body = $body
$msg.Attachments.Add($att)
$smtp.Send($msg)

#Garbage Collection (used for releasing file for deleting)
# Start-Sleep -s 1
# [GC]::Collect()

#Clean-up/Remove File
# Start-Sleep -s 1
if (Test-Path $FilePathName) {Remove-Item $FilePathName}
```

The lines commented out are my attempts at injecting pauses and garbage cleanup, which yielded the same result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dispose the attachment and email objects

```
$att.Dispose();
$msg.Dispose();
```

doing a GC won't help, as you still have root refs

Answer (score 0):

Powershell v2 ships the `Send-MailMessage` Cmdlet which automaticly disposes references.

```
SYNTAX
    Send-MailMessage [-To] <string[]> [-Subject] <string> -From <string> 
    [[-Body] <string>] [[-SmtpServer] <string>] [-Attachments <string[]>]
    [-Bcc <string[]>] [-BodyAsHtml] [-Cc <string[]>] [-Credential <PSCredential>]
    [-DeliveryNotificationOption {None | OnSuccess | OnFailure | Delay | Never}]
    [-Encoding <Encoding>] [-Priority {Normal | Low | High}]
    [-UseSsl] <CommonParameters>]
```

In your case this would be something like:

```
$emailFrom = 'noreply@localhost'
$emailTo = 'aaron@localhost'
$smtpServer = 'localhost'

$FileName='myfile.csv'
$FilePathName= [System.Io.Path]::Combine('c:\temp\', $FileName)

$subject = 'Emailing: ' + $FileName
$body = 'This message as been sent with the following file or link attachments: ' + $FileName

Send-MailMessage -To $emailTo -From $emailFrom -Subject $subject -Body $body -Attachments $filePathName -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)

#Clean-up/Remove File
if (Test-Path $FilePathName) {Remove-Item $FilePathName}
```

See [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347693.aspx) for further details.